# D3 Tooltip Having Trouble Understanding Source Code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble with this d3 extension - https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/blob/master/index.js

My problem is I don't really understand the source code. I understand when specific things are called, but now how it relates to the entire extension.

For example, on this line: https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/blob/master/index.js#L42 they declare

```
function tip(vis) {
      svg = getSVGNode(vis)
      if (!svg) return
      point = svg.createSVGPoint()
      rootElement.appendChild(node)
    }
```

But I don't understand why if I console log `tip` I get this function back to me. Because later in the code it makes calls to `tip` such as here https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/blob/master/index.js#L52

```
   tip.show = function() {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
      if (args[args.length - 1] instanceof SVGElement) target = args.pop()

      var content = html.apply(this, args),
          poffset = offset.apply(this, args),
          dir     = direction.apply(this, args),
          nodel   = getNodeEl(),
          i       = directions.length,
          coords,
          scrollTop  = document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
            rootElement.scrollTop,
          scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft ||
            rootElement.scrollLeft

      nodel.html(content)
        .style('opacity', 1).style('pointer-events', 'all')

      while (i--) nodel.classed(directions[i], false)
      coords = directionCallbacks.get(dir).apply(this)
      nodel.classed(dir, true)
        .style('top', (coords.top + poffset[0]) + scrollTop + 'px')
        .style('left', (coords.left + poffset[1]) + scrollLeft + 'px')

      return tip
    }
```

I've never seen this before where `tip` is declared like a normal function like that and then you add methods to it later.

I'm more used to something like

```
class Tip {
/**
 * Register actions and filters, plus parse IS settings
 *
 * @uses add_action, add_filter, self::get_settings
 * @return null
 */
function __construct() {
```

So can someone explain what is happening here to me? I'm particularly interested in line [130](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/blob/master/index.js#L130). I'm trying to alter in the source code how directions are handled because my implementation is throwing errors.

My understanding is that it starts by assigning `direction` this way `direction = d3TipDirection` and then that line (130) reassigns it to the function passed when I call

```
var tip = d3.tip()
.direction(function(d) {
  if (d === 'Freshly Milled Bread' || d === 'Freshly Peeled Banana'){return 'ne';}
  if (d === 'Salt') {return 'nw';}
});
```

But it breaks for me at [line 71](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/blob/master/index.js#L71) when it manipulates `dir` (a derivative of `direction`) in a way I don't understand. I get can't call `apply` on `undefined` error.

So a general overview of the plugin architecture plus a more specific explanation of my error when it comes to the `direction` property and my function therein would be very helpful and most appreciated.